# Почему некорректно работает line-height в input?

Tags: css

Есть простой инпут для него задан css:

```css
.form__input {
  border: 1px solid #AEB1C8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 13px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E6E8F1;
  color: #444188;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="form__input js-email-input" id="email-input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="">
```

Свойство line-height работает некорректно.

Если я задаю `line-height = 16px`, то высота самого поля составляет 19px, но если я задам `line-height = 18px`, то высота инпута уже будет 18px и свойство срабатывает правильно. В чем проблема? Почему я не могу задать `line-height = 1`? Все значения более 18px срабатывают корректно.

Comment: Свойство `line-height` устанавливает расстояние между строками... `input` редактирует всего одну строку... Что ты хочешь от него добиться применяя `line-height`?

Comment: Возможно вам нужно указать `1rem` или `1em`?

Comment: @ksa line-height регулирует именно высоту одной строки. Изменение расстояния между строками это уже следствие

Comment: А объяснение происходящего вероятно где-то тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425205

Comment: Вместе или вместо `line-height` попробуй `height` править.